# Mongodb connection with php

Tags: php, mongodb, php-extension

### While connecting Mongodb with php it is returning an empty object.

The versions are:

- php version `7.0.31`
- php mongodb extension `1.5.1`
- mongodb version `3.4.16`

[image]

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/database");

var_dump($manager);
```

#### It returns empty object

*`/var/www/html/file/mongocall.php:12:`*

```
  object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)[1]
      public 'uri' => string 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/database' (length=53)
      public 'cluster' => 
      array (size=0) empty
```

got the result after executing

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$m= new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");`

Comment: Thats fine if you are getting cluster empty

Comment: It will work fine even after cluster is blank, If you are facing any issue running query than post that errors

Comment: Have you tried using the connection? Does it work or not? Is there an actual issue?

Comment: @harashvirani thanks for the reply . i trying to display the collection it shows error " Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::listCollections() " code "$collections = $manager->listCollections();

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo "amount of documents in $collection: ";
    echo $collection->count(), "\n";
}"